# how to connect my android HTC device for debugging?

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, nullpointerexception

can I connect my Android emulator to a device (HTC Wildfire Android 2.2.1)?

Actually, my app is working fine in the emulator, but when I tried to install my application in the device, it is crashing.

To debug this issue I want to run my app in the device, connecting it directly instead of checking in the emulator.

Comment: Its not "connect my android emulator to device"? but i think you want to run app on Device

Answer (score 2):

1) Download HTC Sync Manager
http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

2) Then you need to download the "USB Driver" for the particular phone you have. So for the HTC One M9 Phone I have, I had to download the HTC USB Drivers from here:
http://www.theandroidsoul.com/download-htc-one-m9-drivers-for-windows-adb-fastboot-74714/

3) Turn on "USB Debugging" for you phone.
For the HTC One M9, go to

Settings -> About->Software Information->More->Build Number

Click Build Number 7 times until it says that you are a developer.

Then go to

Settings-> Developer Options -> Make sure "USB Debugging" is checked.

4) Plug your phone into your laptop and run your app from Android Studio.

Comment: I managed to enable debug mode for my HTC One M9 Plus after turn on (i) USB debugging (from your tips :-) and (ii) Download SDK Manager > Extra Tools > Google USB Driver. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an entry in /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file for your HTC device, You can get the vendor ID for HTC from [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html), which is 0bb4... If **51-android.rules** file doesn't exists in your system you need to create that file and add following line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"
```

Next you need to restart the adb server using following commands

```
su
$ adb kill-server
$ adb start-server
$ adb devices
```

For more details see [this link](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19546/9741).

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Above got it right for most people here is the google link with some more detail.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

FYI if running sudo fastboot/adb works then you probably have the debian packages installed for fastboot and adb.

While that is nice and easy to do they are rarely updated and you will run into issues sooner or later. Your best bet is to follow the directions on the firmware page, download the android sdk and add the platform_tools folder to your system wide env_vars. Then you will be able to update with a simple command and be able to execute fastboot/adb from anywhere without root (as long as you install in a non root location). You wouldn't believe how many people have fastboot/adb errors and you can ask them did you follow the direction on the firmware page? They will swear they did and you will later find out they are running the Debian packages, not the updated sdk bin (may save you from a nightmare one day). There is much to be said for doing things the right way :)

Here's [Google Firmware Page READ THE FLASHING DIRECTIONS FROM START TO FINISH!!](https://developers.google.com/android/images)